Java doesn't open local files when using debugger
I have a program in written in java where I use printwriter to type into a txt file. When I press f5 in vscode to run and debug, the txt file is empty. But when I use cmd and use the javac and java commands, the items I want to write are written into the txt file.
Example of a java program that creates the same issue as described:
import java.io.*;

public class Count {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("count1m.txt");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
            pw.println(i);
        }
        pw.close();
    }
}


Try File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "count1m.txt"); PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("count1m.txt"); and you should probably be using a try-with-Resources.

Yea.  The file most likely >is< being written ... but you are looking for it in the wrong place.  This is a classic newbie problem: not understanding how relative pathnames are understood by (ultimately) the operating systems.

Have you looked for the file in another location? I frequently print a Date to get a timestamp for exactly this reason - be certain I look at the file I think I’m looking at.

Because the VSCode will use the workspace folder as the work directory default.

cwd - The working directory of the program. Defaults to ${workspaceFolder}.

Which may not be the folder with your count1m.txt.
When you run it in cmd, you may be in the count1m.txt folder, so it works correctly.
So I suggest changing the count1m.txt to an absolute path or configuring the work directory in VSCode run configuration.

How do I change the work directory in the VSCode run config?

@EvanLiu Refer to this docs: configuration-options

you should modify the launch.json file, located in the .vscode folder of your project directory.
{   "version": "0.2.0",   
     "configurations": [    {
     "type": "java",
     "name": "Debug (Launch)",
     "request": "launch",
     "mainClass": "Count",
     "projectName": "your-project-name",
     ***"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"***}   
] }

